# omxplayer exits with 15s delay when launched using QProcess

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qprocess, omxplayer

In my Qt5.9.2 under RPi3 I launch omxplayer in the following way:

```
QProcess *_omx = new QProcess(this);

void MyQPlayer::play(QString uri)
{
    QStringList args;
    args << "-o" << "0" << "-i" << "0";
    args << "omxplayer";
    args << "--vol=-6000";
    args << "-I" << "-s";
    args << "-o" << "hdmi" << uri;
    _omx->start("stdbuf", args, QProcess::Unbuffered | QProcess::ReadWrite);
}
```

I need to use `stdbuf` to avoid buffering, otherwise I cannot read in "real-time" the output from the application.

When the video ends, omxplayer should exits immediately - and it does when I launch it from command line:

```
$ stdbuf -o 0 -i 0 omxplayer --vol=6000 -I -s -o hdmi myfile.mp4
```

Instead, when launched from my application, once the video has ended it remains in execution for about 15s before exits. I catch the `finished()` signal and it confirms it exited nicely: exit code = 0 and exit status = NormalExits.

I'm not sure if this other information is useful or is completely another issue, but I report here anyway.
To pause the video I send on the pipe the letter 'p':

```
void MyPlayer::pause()
{
    qDebug() << "toggle pause";
    if (_omx->state() == QProcess::Running)
    {
        _omx->write("p");
    }
}
```

the debug print tells me the function is actually called every time I invoke the function, but often I need to call it multiple times to actually pause or resume the video execution.

It should not be an issue with buffering because my command line *should* avoid that.

Comment: Have you tried the same code on a PC, not on a raspberry?

Comment: Good point. Not yet. I'm going to try it as soon as possible.

Comment: Try to use [PiOmxTextures](https://github.com/carlonluca/pot). It's much more convenient than omxplayer for RPi.

Comment: @eyllanesc as far as I understand omxplayer is not available for other architectures but the RPi one.

Comment: @eska2000 I'm going to give it a try, but I would understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: @Mark You can download [complete image](http://thebugfreeblog.blogspot.com/2015/11/fully-optimised-raspbian-jessie-with.html) with compiled player. It must work.

Comment: Of course. I was talking about my code.